# Syntax highlighting error in syncolor.vim with VIM 8.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, sudo, vim, vi

I recently installed VIM 8.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. When I open vim, it outputs an error:

```
> vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim:
line   36:
E254: Cannot allocate color Orange1
E254: Cannot allocate color Orange1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I hit enter, it opens without syntax highlighting (but with a colorscheme, the colors change slightly if I change :colorscheme to something different).

But if I run as root, it opens with syntax highlighting.

```
sudo vim ~/.vimrc
```

I assumed it was a permission issue, so I set syncolor.vim to be readable by all:

```
> ll /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Dec 22 23:29 /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

Still no luck. Then I wondered if vim was set to something different under root than under my user:

```
> which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
> /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 22 2016 23:01:25)


> sudo which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
> sudo /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 22 2016 23:01:25)
```

My next thought was that root's TERM was different:

```
> echo $TERM
xterm-256color
> sudo echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Both root and my own user are using the same .vimrc file:

```
echo $MYVIMRC
/home/aaron/.vimrc
```

I'm at a loss. What else could be different between my user and root that would cause colors not to load?

Comment: Well, I know this is old, but your tests for `$VARIABLES` are invalid.  They are expanded *before* sudo is ran.  Instead, you should test like `sudo bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE'`.  (notice the single quotes)  you can check with `$PATH` or `$LOGNAME` which are usually different between you and sudo.

Comment: Hi! I just saw this comment now. I will try that and see if it does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely 'defaults.vim' in your '$VIMRUNTIME' folder, which in this case would have likely meant.. `/usr/local/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim`

I've just been trying to fix the same issue on OpenVMS with vim 8.1, and that turned out to be the cause - loading vim with `vim -u [some garbage filename]` forces vim to load without the system .vimrc, but also without the system defaults.vim